# Permutation with no two vowels next to each other

Tags: permutations

Question : find number of arrangements of the word TRIANGLE in which no two vowels are next to each other.

My attempt : $5! ( ^6P_3) =14,400$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

There are $5$ consonants and $3$ vowels.

Vowels can be selected in $\dbinom{6}{3}$ ways.

The vowels be arranged in $3!$ ways

The consonants can be arranged in $5!$ ways.

In total we have $\dbinom{6}{3}\times3!\times5!=14400$ ways.

Comment: Thank you .  I will accept your answer with green tick :)

Comment: @user122343 You are welcome :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I did. I just did it back.

Answer (score 0):

The consonants can be arranged in $5!$ ways.  There are then six "slots" available for single vowels:  one slot on each side of the five consonants:

_ C _ C _ C _ C _ C _

You can choose which of those six slots to fill in ${6 \choose 3}$ ways.  And for each such choice there are $3!$ ways to put the three vowels.

Thus:  $5! \times (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4)/(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) \times 3! = 14400  $ ways.

Comment: How do you figure 7 slots? There are 6.

Comment: You didn't do choosing properly. You should either get rid of the extra $3!$ or add a $(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $5! \times (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4)/(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) \times 3!=14400$ but not $5! \times (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4)/(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) \times 3!\ne86400$